# Customising RESTAdapter in ember

Tags: json, api, ember.js

I have an ember application which has two routes, user and subject. I'm (trying) to use the RESTAdapter to get data from an api, but the api does not return the data in the necessary format, ie instead of returning:

```
{
  "user": {
    id: "1",
    name: "John Doe"
  }
}
```

my api returns:

```
 {
    id: "1",
    name: "John Doe"
  }
```

I've been reading through a lot of related questions and have surmised that I need to use some kind of serializer within my adapter to customize it for my JSON. So far I have come up with this, based on answers and examples:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://example.com',
    serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
        extractMany: function(loader, json, type, records) {
        var root = this.rootForType(type);
        var roots = this.pluralize(root);

        formattedJson = {};
        formattedJson[roots] = json.entries;
        delete formattedJson.pagination;
        this._super(loader, formattedJson, type, records);  
        }
    })
});
```

But it doesn't seem to be having any effect. I'm also wondering if I need to write a different adapter for each model as I don't think the above can handle creating both `users` and a `subjects` roots. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per type serializers are super easy in ED as of 1.0, see documentation below, and this example should work for your user model.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

```
App.UserSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload = {user:payload};
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id, requestType);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k, do I use this instead of the serializer I defined above?

Comment: Yes, that way above was the old way of defining the serializer